# Using IF in excel for a range of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a conditional format formula to state if `F3:F10 = Y` then `Y` not `N`.

I am trying:

```
=IF(F3:F10 = "Y","Y","N")
```

I am doing this for conditional formatting, basically looking for it to read the column for all "Y's" if that's the case `F11` should be `"Y"` if one or more in the range of `F3 - F10` are `"N"` then the result should be `"N"`

PS this is my first post here, tried to find the answer first elsewhere but I was unable to locate this specific question. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead: `If(Countif(F3:F10, "N")=0, "Y", "N")`

Comment: That worked, thank you!